# Changing the Deployment Strategy from RollingUpdate to Recreate using Golang

Tags: go, kubernetes, deployment, patch

I have a very big issue. We have a large number of deployments for a component which up until now were using the RollingUpdate deployment strategy type.

```
spec:
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
```

Now a new design decision needs us to move this to a `Recreate` strategy, which would be fairly easy if we could just write a shell script to call `kubectl patch` and use the `$retainKeys` method [described in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment-using-the-retainkeys-strategy).

However, we use a custom tool written in Golang to manage our gazillion deployments and we'd like to integrate this into our regular update cycle and avoid this hack. Therefore, I've changed the code to look like this:

```
deploy := &appsv1.Deployment{
        Spec: appsv1.DeploymentSpec{
            Strategy: appsv1.DeploymentStrategy{
                Type: appsv1.RecreateDeploymentStrategyType,
            },
```

Obviously, when we run the update procedure, the tool fails with the following error:

```
Error updating *v1.Deployment Deployment.apps "cluster-agent" is invalid: spec.strategy.rollingUpdate: Forbidden: may not be specified when strategy `type` is 'Recreate'
```

According to the above link, the `retainKeys` trick has to be used but I have not managed to find out how that can be done from within Golang.

I can see in the k8s api sources that the patch strategy supports the retainKeys method:

```
Strategy DeploymentStrategy `json:"strategy,omitempty" patchStrategy:"retainKeys"
```

But would someone be so kind as to let me know how can I specify the `retainKeys` list within my Golang structs/code? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you managed to resolve it? There are some ideas which can be helpful. First you can use `dynamic` client instead of `typed` one where you will be able to choose a merge type (with types) explicitly while updating the existing resources. Types can be: `ApplyPatchType` - server side apply or `StrategicMergePatchType` - this is an equivalent of `retainKeys` method. Please find some details and examples [here](https://ymmt2005.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/04/14/An_example_of_using_dynamic_client_of_k8s.io/client-go)

Comment: In the end, I didn't get it to work, so we just reverted back to using a bash script which iterated through a list of namespaces and called kubectl to make the change. Your suggestion is interesting, but it is too late now, but perhaps a good lead for the future reader. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Latest update from this [issue](https://github.com/gimlet-io/onechart/issues/35) works

```
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate: null
    type: Recreate
```